# identifying node types

Tags: neo4j

I have a number of nodes of different types by that I mean nodes that have different properties on them.  For instance, I have a number of nodes that all they have is a property of fileName and uploadDate.  If I want to check against all file names do I just need to do

```
START n=node(*) WHERE has(n.File) RETURN n;
```

Is this the best practice (i.e. querying a flattened out database).  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query scans all nodes, this will become slower as your data set grows.

For identifying nodes of a certain type, there are two common approaches:

### Type attribute

Set a property named 'type' (or '_type_' f.e. if you like to mark it as a system property) with the value describing your type, e.g. 'File'.

Then you can lookup nodes through an index like that:

```
start n=node:node_auto_index(type='File') return n;
```

### Type nodes

Connect nodes of a certain type to 'type' node and query over relationships:

```
start type_node=node:node_auto_index(name='File')
match type_node<-[:IS_A]-file
return file;
```

(The Beer Graph on this page http://www.neo4j.org/learn/try is an example for this.)

Comment: Additional info: Neo4j 2.0 will introduce "labels" which can be used to identify a node's type.

You can tag nodes with one or more labels to you group nodes.

Read more in this blog post: http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/01/2013-whats-coming-next-in-neo4j.html